# Android Customize TabHosts Using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-xml

I want to change the background color of the tabs when they're selected and unselected. Also, I wish to add some features to the TabHost like borders.
I already have the tabs created and with the currently content.

To be more specific, I will upload a picture of what I wish to have. It shows three tabs, where the second is selected.

[image: TabHost Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all create tabwidget using tabhost.

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/tabsHorizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                    android:fadingEdge="none"
                    android:showDividers="none" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <!-- <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#EFEFEF" /> -->

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

here n my case i put my tabwidget inside horizontalscroll.

Now create a layout for tab background(i have created as tab_bg.xml) and paste this xml file.

tab_bg.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/horizontal_scroll_padding_topbottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_scroll_padding_leftright"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_scroll_padding_leftright"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/horizontal_scroll_padding_topbottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/tab_txt_view_txt_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can change color as per yours.

Again you create 4 xml file and put it into drawable folder.

In my case i used <1> tab_bg_selecter.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <!--  Active tab -->
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
        <!--  Inactive tab -->
        <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />
        <!--  Pressed tab -->
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
        <!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
            android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    </selector>
```

<2> tab_bg_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient
            android:angle="-90"
            android:centerColor="#6EBD52"
            android:endColor="#6EBD52"
            android:startColor="#6EBD52" />

    </shape>
```

<3> tab_bg_unselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

<4> tab_text_selecter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:color="#C7C7CC" />
</selector>
```

if you want to change your tab text change at the time of selection of tab.

This Answer is lengthy but is fully customized and hope it will useful for you.

Comment: Ok, I got you! I already created it using TabHosts. However, I'm having some issues to make it use the tab_bg.xml.

Comment: please explain your issues on using tab_bg.xml

Comment: I found how to add it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

call this method in oncreate() method

```
setupTabHost();
```

and than use this for setting tabs name as in my case it is A2Z characters

```
for (ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
            charToString = String.valueOf(ch);
            setupTab(new TextView(this), charToString);
        }
```

finally outside of oncreate use this;

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 private void setupTabHost() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
    }              



                private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
        .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return view;
            }
        });
mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
```

}

```
private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        tabTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tabTextView.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
```

It may be helpful for you.

Comment: I used both answers to achieve it. And it is working as a charme. Only, need now to put the borders around tabs. Thank you

Comment: you can put view for border (see my commented field in tabhost) or in drawable part you can put border for tab_bg_unselected.xml with square shape of same color as selected ta color.